# Script to change the folder name for 10,000 folders in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to change the folder name for 10,000 folders in windows.

I have old structure available and I want to change it to new one. For example:

Old structure: C:\Documents to read\Important\Domain\Latest\Today

New structure: C:\Documents\Important\Domain\new\yesterday

Is there any way through which I can change the 10,000 flies by providing folder structure in a batch file?

(old folder structure to new folder structure without impacting the underneath files)

I tried - ren "old file name" "new file name" in command prompt but it is very specific to particular folder.

Please help. I am very new to the command prompt. Any kind of help is very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You state you have 10,000 "folders" and then 10,000 "files". Please clarify. How would the new directorynames be derived from the existing directorynames?

Answer (score 0):

To rename a folder you have to use `mv /home/user/oldname /home/user/newname`
after this you have to use a for loop for all your folder

Comment: Thank you for your reply. does that mean I need to do it on each level of the folder structure? If yes, could you please tell me which loop should I use? Sorry I am very new to scripting

Comment: you can use the for loop like on this page : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86722/how-do-i-loop-through-only-directories-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

Windows has limited batch file capability, so what I've done is:

- `DIR /S /AD /B > files.tsv` to output all the files in bare full format
- import `files.tsv` into Excel
- new column with a formula to generate "after"
- new column with a formula to create a `REN` command, e.g. `="REN """ & A1 & """ """ & B1 & """"`
- paste that column into a batch file `DOIT.BAT`
- very important - backup **all** the files! very easy to mess up
- run `DOIT.BAT`

`DIR /S /AD /B` does recurse into all subdirectories, which is annoying, but it does list them in hierarchical order, so it might be easy to edit out the ones you don't want.

The extra quotes are to make sure spaces in directories and file names for `REN` are handled properly.